# Finding the range of the '.text' section of a process with a known pid

Tags: c, linux, memory, process

1. I know I can read off /proc/[id]/maps but I'm not sure if the first entry is always the .text section.
2. I would have to parse /proc/[id]/maps, is there an api I could call to get the data?

edit- I see pmap just reads that same file. No worries. I'll just read off the first two integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as per above. (these are extra characters to get past the padding.)